# SharePoint Designer Email Message

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have an issue with sending email on SharePoint designer. Every time I add a recipient[image] on To: section it will change to some weird characters. Please see the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

**c:0+.w** indicates the claim identifier for a Windows security group.

**S1-5-21xxx** is the SID of an orphaned object in Active Directory.

It can be a User Object or Group Object that most likely been deleted.

Make sure the user you selected is available in AD.

You could also use following powershell in this [article](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/07/find-and-delete-orphaned-users-in-sharepoint-using-powershell.html) to find and delete Orphaned Users in SharePoint.

Comment: Thanks for your message, all the users I am selecting are available in AD, I even tried with my own account. Another question, do you know why the To: and CC: sections are grayed out. It wont let me to add any users email address there. I can only click on the Select User icon to select someone.

Comment: Whether this issue only occurs in workflow email? Do these users show correctly in SharePoint site?By default, To: and CC: sections are grayed out.

Comment: they all correct in SP site, only happens in SP designer, another question, can I send email to shared mail box using SharePoint designer?

Comment: Clear the designer cache or uninstall and reinstall SharePoint designer to check the results.To send email to shared mailbox, store the shared mailbox email address as a variable within the workflow, then have the email sent to that variable.

Comment: had to create a variable and assign to the email.  it fixed the issue

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enable the account in AD? That did the trick for me.
Simply right click the user in AD and enable account.

[image]

Reload SPD and it should be good to go.